# Upload a file with greater dimension than DefaultMaxRequestBodySize in fasthttp

Tags: go, file-upload, fasthttp

I can not find an example for upload a file with greater dimension than the `DefaultMaxRequestBodySize`. Could you please share how to upload a big file using `fasthttp`?

Unfortunately, I receive the error `body size exceeds the given limit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
s := &fasthttp.Server{
    Handler: requestHandler,

    // Every response will contain 'Server: My super server' header.
    Name: "My super server",

    // Other Server settings may be set here.

    MaxRequestBodySize: 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
}
```

Just set the size when start.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know some option for disable the `MaxRequestBodySize` instead of set a big number?

Comment: @alessiosavi not a fasthttp user, but do not find such a option from the source code.